# How to change the index of previous selected Dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, gridview, indexing

I have gridview with template field of dropdownlist in each row.when i select any value from dropdownlist it will change color of 3rd row below than it.But when i click on another dropdownlist it is changing the color of 3rd row below than it but the index of previous dropdownlist is not changed to 0 i.e"Select".it is still showing the value selected in last dropdown list.I just want when i click on a dropdownlist ,all other dropdownlist should be indexed to 0 i.e "Select" except one which i have clicked.
I am doing following in Selectedindexchange event of dropdownlist:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
               int g1 = gvRow.RowIndex;
               GridView1.Rows[g1].BackColor = Color.White;
         }
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
            int g = row.RowIndex + 3;
            int current_row_index = row.RowIndex;
            int pp = GridView1.Rows.Count;
             GridView1.Rows[g].BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
     }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow up: if you got the answer you were looking for, please mark it as correct. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just use **DropdownName.ClearSelection()** for each of your other dropdown except the one where you are calling Selectedindexchange event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
     protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        int g = row.RowIndex + 3;
        int current_row_index = row.RowIndex;

        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            gvRow.BackColor = Color.White;

            if (gvRow.FindControl("nameOfTheDropdown") != null && gvRow.RowIndex != current_row_index)
            {
                ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("nameOfTheDropdown")).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        GridView1.Rows[g].BackColor = Color.Red;  
     }
```

Regards